# How can I get my chrome extension up and running?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ibm-watson

EDIT: it seems there is an issue in the code. Would anyone know how to fix this error?

The error I am getting is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

contentscript.js:103 (anonymous function)

```
const translatorapikey = "XXX";
const toneanalyzerapikey = "XXX";

function getAPIKeyV2(apikey){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
       xmlRequest.open("POST", "https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token")
       xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")

       xmlRequest.send(encodeURI("grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey&apikey="+apikey));

       xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

         if(xmlRequest.readyState ==4 && xmlRequest.status==200) {

             var parsedData = JSON.parse(xmlRequest.responseText)

             resolve (parsedData.access_token);
         }
     }

     }

  });

}

 var callToneAnalyzer = function (word) {
 var textContent = String(word.selectionText);

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var toneanalyzertoken = getAPIKeyV2(toneanalyzerapikey);
 toneanalyzertoken.then(function(result){
 var inputContent = textContent.replace(/%20/g, "");
 xhr.open("GET", "https://api.us-south.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com/api/v3/tone?sentences=true&version=2016-05-19&text="+inputContent)
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+result);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")

 xhr.send();

 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200){
 var result1 = xhr.responseText;

 var obj = JSON.parse(result1);

 var fulltone  = obj.document_tone.tone_categories;
 var angerTone = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[0].tone_name;
 var angerScore = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[0].score;

 var disgustTone = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[1].tone_name;
 var disgustScore = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[1].score;

 var fearTone = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[2].tone_name;
 var fearScore = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[2].score;

 var joyTone = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[3].tone_name;
 var joyScore = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[3].score;

 var sadnessTone = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[4].tone_name;
 var sadnessScore = obj.document_tone.tone_categories[0].tones[4].score;

  alert(angerTone  + "=  " + angerScore*100 + " %" + ";" + "\n" +  disgustTone + "= "  + disgustScore*100  + " %" + "\n" + fearTone + "= " + fearScore*100 + " %" + "\n" + joyTone + "= " + joyScore*100 + " %" + "\n" + sadnessTone  + "= " + sadnessScore*100 + " %");

     }
 }
 })

};

function Translator(word, lang, langname) {
    var textContent = String(word.selectionText);

    var accesstoken = getAPIKeyV2(translatorapikey);

    accesstoken.then(function(result){
     var inputContent = textContent.replace(/%20/g, " ");
     var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

     if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

     xmlRequest.open("POST", "https://api.us-south.language-translator.watson.cloud.ibm.com/api/v3/translate?version=2018-05-01")
     xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ result);
     xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     var data = {
         "text": inputContent,
         "source": "en",
         "target": String(lang)
     }
     xmlRequest.send(JSON.stringify(data));

 xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xmlRequest.readyState ==4 && xmlRequest.status==200){
         var translatedtext = JSON.parse(xmlRequest.responseText);
         alert("Translated to  " + langname + "\n" + JSON.stringify(translatedtext.translations));
     }
 }

    })
}

function generalTranslator(word) {

    var childname = word.menuItemId;

    if (childname == 'child1') {
        Translator(word, 'es', 'Spanish');
        return;
    }
    if (childname == 'child2') {
        Translator(word, 'ar', 'Arabic');
        return;
    }
    if (childname == 'child3') {
        Translator(word, 'fr', 'French');
        return;
    }
    if (childname == 'child4') {
        Translator(word, 'pt', 'Portuguese');
        return;
    }
    if (childname == 'child5') {
        Translator(word, 'de', 'German');
        return;
    }
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "IBM Watson API V1",
    id: 'parent',
    contexts: ["selection"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Translate to Spanish",
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child1",
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: generalTranslator
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Translate to Arabic",
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child2",
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: generalTranslator
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Translate to French",
    parentId: "parent",
    id: 'child3',
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: generalTranslator
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Translate to Portuguese",
    parentId: "parent",
    id: 'child4',
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: generalTranslator
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Translate to German",
    parentId: "parent",
    id: 'child5',
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: generalTranslator
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Tone Analyzer",
    parentId: "parent",
    id: 'child6',
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: callToneAnalyzer
});
```

For context I am not a developer or a software eng. Just a casual person intrigued by IBM Watson's [Tone Analyzer](https://tone-analyzer-demo.ng.bluemix.net/). I wanted to build my own Chrome extension that can analyze the tone of the messages I write from my laptop, so I followed all the steps described in IBM's [documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/artificial-intelligence/tutorials/how-to-create-a-browser-extension-that-leverages-ibm-watson-cognitive-api/). To my surprise, despite my limited technical knowledge, I managed to go through the steps described in this doc.

After following up to step 5, I see my extension succesfully displayed in chrome://extensions/

However, I can't reproduce Step 6. When I right click, the IBM watson API menu is not displayed.

What am I missing? Would anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Switch to a tab with a normal web page and try there. Reload the tab if it didn't work.

Comment: I had tried that but after analyzing again, it seems the issue is in the code - more details in the below comment